# How to exit main thread from a thread

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading

I have a main script that runs a discord bot. But I want it to exit at a specific time of the day. So I want to make a thread that checks for the time and kills the main thread.

```
now = datetime.datetime.now().time() 

def time_checker():
    while True:
        if now.hour == 19:
            thread.interrupt_main()

thread = threading.Thread(target=time_checker, daemon=True)
thread.start()
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: How is this code being run? Why not just exit from the `time_checker`, which will end the `thread` thread. Once that's exited, unless there's something from stopping it, your program will exit as well if there no more code to run.

Comment: This is at the beginning of my script. After this part there is a loop. I want to exit that loop with this thread.

Comment: You could just call `exit` or a similar function; although those have downsides if you need to do any cleanup before exiting.

Comment: exit or quit just close the thread and not the main one.